# How to automate a SAP GUI process without using Script Recording and playback option

Tags: python, vba, user-interface, automation, sap-gui

I need to automate a SAP GUI process. But I don't have SAP GUI Scripting and Playback authorizations. It could be great someone have option to do this with Python or VBA.

Comment: "SAP GUI for Windows" is a Windows software. Can't you use any other [Windows robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface_testing)?

Comment: I just try Microsoft Power Automate with image capturing technology to do this. But it is not 100% success.